# "import torch" giving error "from torch._C import *, DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found"

Tags: python, torch

I am currently using Python 3.5.5 on Anaconda and I am unable to import torch. It is giving me the following error in Spyder:

```
Python 3.5.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 12 2018, 17:44:09) [MSC v.1900 
64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 6.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-eb42ca6e4af3>", line 1, in <module>
    import torch

  File "C:\Users\trish\Anaconda3\envs\virtual_platform\lib\site-
  packages\torch\__init__.py", line 76, in <module>
    from torch._C import *

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Many suggestions on the internet say that the working directory should not be the same directory that the torch package is in, however I've manually set my working directory to C:/Users/trish/Downloads, and I am getting the same error.

Also I've already tried the following: reinstalling Anaconda and all packages from scratch, and I've ensured there is no duplicate "torch" folder in my directory.

Pls help! Thank you!

Comment: from the pytorch website: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/windows.html#import-error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this similar problem in windows 10...

Solution:

- Download **win-64/intel-openmp-2018.0.0-8.tar.bz2** from https://anaconda.org/anaconda/intel-openmp/files
- Extract it and put the dll files in **Library\bin** into 
  `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin`
- Make sure your cuda directory is added to your `%PATH%` environment variable

Comment: what if we don't have the NVIDIA ?

Comment: @DavidGladson You can put those dlls in C:\Python35\ folder. It will work.

Comment: This didnt work for me, none of the other suggestions did either. But by changing the python version from 3.6.8 to 3.6.7 it suddenly sprang to life.

Comment: @Nagamani I tried putting the file in `C:\Python37` folder but it still doesn't work. And I do not have NVIDIA as well.

Comment: @AdarshRavi Okay. Sorry, I am not sure about that. May be could you please check C:\Python37 path is set in environment variable? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. In my case I didn't want the GPU version of pytorch. 
I uninstalled it. The version was    pytorch: 0.3.1-py36_cuda80_cudnn6he774522_2 peterjc123.

The problem is that cuda and cudnn . then installed with the following command and now it works!

```
conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch-cpu
```

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered the same problem when I used a conda environment with python 3.6.8 and pytorch installed by conda from channel -c pytorch.

Here is what worked for me:

1:) `conda create -n envName python=3.6 anaconda`

2:) `conda update -n envName conda`

3:) `conda activate envName`

4:) `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=9.0 -c pytorch`

and then tested torch with the given code:

5:) `python -c "import torch; print(torch.cuda.get_device_name(0))"`

Note: 5th step will return your gpu name if you have a cuda compatible gpu

**Summary: I just created a conda environment containing whole anaconda and then to tackle the issue of unmatched conda version I updated conda of new environment from the base environment and then installed pytorch in that environment and tested pytorch.**

For CPU version, here is the link for my another answer: https://gist.github.com/peterjc123/6b804651288e76db7b5fabe5348e1f03#gistcomment-2842825

https://gist.github.com/peterjc123/6b804651288e76db7b5fabe5348e1f03#gistcomment-2842837

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem and fixed it by re-installing numpy with mkl (Intel's math kernel library)
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Download the right `.whl` for your machine. For me it was numpy‑1.14.5+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl (python 3.6, windows, 64-bit)
and then install using pip.

```
pip install numpy‑1.14.5+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using a Windows 10 computer with an NVIDIA GeForce graphics card. NVIDIA showed I had CUDA 10.1, but I was getting this error when running `import torch` in Jupyter Lab and suspected it had something to do with CUDA support.

I fixed this problem by downloading and installing the [CUDA Toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit) directly from NVIDIA. It installed all required Visual Studio components. When I returned to Jupyter Lab, `import torch` ran without error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed the right version of pytorch for your enviroment. I had the same problem I was using pytorch on windows but I had the default package installed which was meant for cuda 8. So I reinstalled the pytorch package for cpu which was what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with running torch installed with pure pip and solved it by switching to conda. 
Following steps:

1. uninstall python 3.6 from python.org (if exists)
2. install [miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html)
3. install torch in conda ("conda install pytorch -c pytorch")

Issue with pip installation:

```html
import torch
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 78, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

After switching to conda it works fine. I believe the issue was resolved by conda through installing the vs_redist 2017

> vs2017_runtime            15.4.27004.2010        peterjc123

But I have tried it w/o conda and it did not help. Could not find how to check (and tweak) Python's vs_redist.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows10 Solution(This worked for my system):**

I was having the same issue in my system. Previously I was using Python 3.5 and I created a virtual environment named pytorch_test using the virtualenv module because I didn't want to mess up my tensorflow installation(which took me a lot of time). I followed every instruction but it didn't seem to work. I installed python 3.6.7 added it to the path. Then I created the virtual environment using:

`virtualenv --python=3.6 pytorch_test`

Then go to the destination folder

`cd D:\pytorch_test`

and activate the virtual environment entering the command in cmd:

`.\Scripts\activate`

After you do this the command prompt will show:

`(pytorch_test) D:\pytorch_test>`

Update pip if you have not done it before using:

`(pytorch_test) D:\pytorch_test>python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Then go for installing numpy+mkl from the site:

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Choose the correct version from the list if you have python 3.6.7 go with the wheel file:
numpy‑1.15.4+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl (For 64 bit)

(Note if the whole thing doesnot work just go with simple numpy installation and mkl installation separately)
Then go for installing openmp using:

`(pytorch_test) D:\pytorch_test>pip install intel-openmp`

Now you are done with the prerequisites. To install pytorch go to the previous versions site:
https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/

Here select the suitable version from the list of Windows Binaries. For example I am having CUDA 9.0 installed in my system with python 3.6.7 so I went with the gpu version:

cu90/torch-1.0.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

(There are two available versions 0.4.0 and 1.0.0 for pytorch, I went with 1.0.0)

After downloading the file install it using pip(assuming the whl file is in **D:**).You have to do this from the virtual environment pytorch_test itself:

`(pytorch_test) D:\pytorch_test>pip install D:\torch-1.0.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

Prerequisites like six, pillow will be installed automatically.
Then once everything is done, install the models using torchvision.
Simply type :

`(pytorch_test) D:\pytorch_test>pip install torchvision`

To check everything is working fine try the following script:

```
import torch
test = torch.rand(4, 7)
print(test)
```

If everything was good then it wont be an issue. Whenever there is an issue like this it is related to version mismatch of one or more dependencies. This also occurred during tensorflow installation.

Deactivate the following virtual environment using the command deactivate in the cmd:

`(pytorch_test) D:\pytorch_test>deactivate`

This is the output of **pip list** in my system:

```
Package      Version
------------ -----------
intel-openmp 2019.0
mkl          2019.0
numpy        1.16.2
Pillow       6.0.0
pip          19.0.3
setuptools   41.0.0
six          1.12.0
torch        1.0.0
torchvision  0.2.2.post3
wheel        0.33.1
```

Hope this helps. This is my first answer in this community, hope you all find it helpful. I setup pytorch today in the afternoon after trying all sorts of combinations. The same import problem occurred to me while installing CNTK and tensorflow. Anyway I kept them separate in different virtual environments so that I can use them anytime.