# torch error in pycharm while importing from the conda environment

Tags: python

I have issue while after installing pytorch in conda environment. I can't able to import torch. it gives error like

> File "", line 1, in    File
>   "C:\Users\Ahsan\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\torch__init__.py",
>   line 81, in 
>       from torch._C import * ImportError: DLL load failed: The file cannot be accessed by the system.

although the interpreter path is ok because it can import tensorflow as it is installed in the particular environment

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49395819/import-torch-giving-error-from-torch-c-import-dll-load-failed-the-specif

Comment: yes but couldn't find solution there